# CakePHP - how should I layout and name my tables

Tags: php, database, cakephp, foreign-keys

It's a song and lyrics database. I'm trying to bake an app from my database, which looks like this: (every table does have an ID, I just left it out..)

```
songs
    song_name

artists
    artist_name

songs_singers
    artist_id (FOREIGN KEY artists.id)
    song_id (FOREIGN KEY songs.id)

songs_writers
    artist_id (FOREIGN KEY artists.id)
    song_id (FOREIGN KEY songs.id)

song_views
    song_id (FOREIGN KEY songs.id)

videos
    song_id (FOREIGN KEY songs.id)

video_views
    video_id (FOREIGN KEY videos.id)
```

Writers and singers both overlap, i.e. some writers sing and some singers write.

When I bake the songs table, I get this error:
    **Error: Table singers for model Singer was not found in datasource default.**

I think the problem is that CakePHP wants me to create a new model for singers, so I'll have to end up duplicating the names of writers and singers in a new table singers. I just want the names stored in artists and have both song_singers and song_writers link to that table with foreign key IDs.

songs have many:

- views
- videos

videos have many:

- views

both writers and singers have many:

- songs

What should I do?

EDIT: Here is the model SongsSinger.

---

```
class SongsSinger extends AppModel {

public $validate = array(
    'song_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'artist_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
);


public $belongsTo = array(
    'Song' => array(
        'className' => 'Song',
        'foreignKey' => 'song_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Artist' => array(
        'className' => 'Artist',
        'foreignKey' => 'artist_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
}
```

Comment: Can you put up the model for 'songs_singers'?  It sounds like you already have a model 'Singers', however the database has songs_singers.  So when cake looks at the database it can't find the correct table.

Comment: check out http://cakeapp.com it offers a GUI for managing tables.

Comment: @iexiak - done. I don't have a model Singers. I'm just using the Bake feature to create everything from the database. It gives these options for models: (**Possible Models based on your current database:
1. Artist, 2. SongView, 3. Song, 4. SongsSinger, 5. SongsWriter, 6. VideoView, 7. Video**). I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but in the model I just put up - SongsSinger belongs to Song and Artist. Shouldn't it be the other way around? (singers have many songs.)

Comment: You might just need to do some manual work, bake expects you to follow the conventions. By the way, the convention says that join tables [should be named in alphabetical order](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm), so your `songs_singers` should be `singers_songs`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, it's been about a thousand years since I baked...

As far as the relationship - it seems right to me.
Artists have many songsingers.  Songs have many songsingers.  Songsingers belongs to artists and songs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any singers (you called them artists).

Your database should be:

```
songs_artists
    artist_id (FOREIGN KEY artists.id)
    song_id (FOREIGN KEY songs.id)
```